# Save, Load and Replay game. c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Basically as part of a team I have had to create a pacman like game for my university course, just zombies instead of ghosts. 
We have built all of the game so far and it seems to work really well. Our current problem is that we have to Save a game (with a username and score), Load the game into the position it was once saved, with the correct username and score, and finally be able to offer a replay option where the user can see all the moves that they have previously made (as well as the moves the zombies have made). The zombies will always make the same moves that the user makes as they are designed to chase the user.

My question is what would be the best way to do the save, load and reload options? We cannot use vectors, stacks or queues. We can only really use strings, arrays and other basic variables.
We were thinking to do the reload first by adding everything onto the end of a string and then popping the last value off the string. We could then delay each one by a second and the user will be able to see his/her moves.

As for Saving we were unsure, there are also holes (0 symbols) and pills (* symbols) to take into account. So the position of character, zombies, pills and holes will need to be saved. The character can start from any random position and pretty much everything else is placed after.

The way we do the loading will depend on the way you suggest we do the saving.

Does anyone have any suggestions of the way we should do save, load and replay?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you use collections like vectors etc...?

Comment: @cppguy Just the lecturer putting extra bounds on the task. Making us think about the more basic things like Arrays, files, strings, etc.

Comment: You should consider using XML.  There are libs out there to help manage it.

Comment: Arrays are just as useful as vectors. You just need to manage them yourself.

Comment: @RageD the less management you have to do in your code, the cleaner, more concise and more fault tolerant it will be. floats can hold integer values... it doesn't mean i use them to hold my ints

Comment: @cppguy: I agree, however, if he is not allowed to use these constructs, he still has the same power. He could implement his own versions as well if he felt ambitious (maybe not as efficient, but still possible).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I could think of is saving the user inputs.

This way you could easily replay the game by sending the inputs to the game engine (this may require a lot of restructuring depending on the design of the game engine). To accelerate the loading you could also save the game state at the time of the save (through serialization).

That's the idea, how to do it... you need an ever-expanding  array to record the user-input, so let's use a linked-list.

```
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next_node;
};
//Google for the rest of the code, it is a reeeaaallly
//    basic/fundamental data structure.
```

The data would be the user-inputs and the time they happened.
To save the data, you simply have to iterate through the linked-list and append it to a std::ostream& (to be generic, a std::ofstream& to be specific).

You may add some other useful information (such as the game state and the highscore) before or after the user inputs (or even in another file, which would really make sense for the highscores).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read up on some serialization. I wrote some articles on it here, but this is going to be overkill for you guys: http://www.randygaul.net/2013/01/05/c-reflection-part-5-automated-serialization/

You can use some very simple serialization to write out the moves of each zombie into a file. Then when you want to reload this information you deserialize the information in the file. Each move will likely be stored in some form of a linked list so you'll have to come up with a way of recreating such lists upon deserialization.

Your question is really broad so my answer has to be quite broad as well. Really it's up to you to research a solution and implement it.

Comment: The link is broken.